# Bootstrap not working properly in angular project

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

It's the first time I am creating an Angular project. I'm having trouble with bootstrap in my project. I installed bootstrap, jquery, popper.js, and included them in the angular.json file.

```
"styles": [              
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
"scripts": [        
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"             
]
```

Bootstrap classes are working but the dropdowns are not working properly, I think something is wrong with bootstrap.min.js. The dropdown should open after clicking on it:
[image]

But in my case it is already open:
 [image]

Comment: I dont know why but only put 
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

in styles.css works for me

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 ways you can use bootstrap in angular

npm install bootstrap --save

1. In angular.json file add the path of the bootstrap module like:

   ```
     "styles": [
         "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
         "src/styles.css"              
       ]
   ```
2. In index.html file add the bootstrap.css file as an external css.
3. You can include the bootstrap.css into the style.css or style.scss file like:

   @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Bootstrap is installed successfully and no problem with css classes. But the problem is that .js seems to be not working as the dropdown is working wrong way

Comment: Use bootstrap.bundle.min.js or be sure you have Popper.js in your dependencies

Answer (score 2):

please do this :

```
"styles": [
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "src/styles.css"
],

"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use one of the angular bootstrap libraries that re-implement the bootstrap components with angular and therefore integrate well with the rest of angular. This removes the dependencies on bootstrap javascript & jquery.

Here are two options (no particular order).

- https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
- https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you are following any course, check the bootstrap version used by the instructor.
Bootstrap 4 is not same as Bootstrap 5.

specify the version used by the instructor while installing bootstrap.
ie.. **npm install bootstrap@4 --save**

Answer (score -2):

Simply install `npm i bootstrap` also you can check documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap)

After install Simply add below line in `angular.json` file under `styles` array

```
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Content here -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Checkout more dropdown in bootstrap documentation [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

you can check here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kccg2m?file=src%2Findex.html)